# Very simple mechanics question (pendulum)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Suppose there's a rigid rod, and at the end of the rod, there's a weight. If the rod (i.e "rigid pendulum") is rotating forming the shape of a cone, like this picture: [image]

(a) What would be the forces acting on it ? My book (by Kleppner and Kolenkow) says the only forces would be the one along $L$ - the tension T - and the downward force $mg$, but wouldn't be there a force towards the axis, along $r$?

(b) How does the vertical componenent of the force $T$ balance?

Answer (score 1):

There **is** a force toward the center of the circle - it is the vector sum of the two forces you have mentioned. The key point is that a point-like body only feels the total force acting upon it, no matter how you expand it in some (not necessarily orthogonal) coordinate system.

Since the body moves in a circle, its acceleration $\vec{a}$ points inwards towards the center of the circle. Thus, by applying Newton's second law, you have
$$\Sigma \vec{F}=m\vec{a}$$
This means in your case that the vertical component of the tension balances gravity, while its horizontal component leads to the motion in a circle.

Answer (score 0):

1.There's no such thing called centrifugal force balance,because centrifugal force is a fictitious force, it's only the centripetal force toward the axis of rotation,this force is equal to the horizontal component of the tension force of L while the vertical component is canceled out by the force of gravity.